# Lotus Notes : Fetch the information from share folder text file and store in Lotus notes database automatically

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus, lotus-formula

I am working on remotely on client system. I don't have knowledge on lotus notes.
There are some automated job executed in database which read the text file from share folder and store the information in lotus notes database. And another automated process generated report with that information.

Problem:
I have no idea which automated job are executed and also i checked in database but i didn't get anything. Can some please help here where i have to check or any other way to resolve this problem.

Comment: Vote to close: Too broad.  It's probably an agent in a database.  There could be hundreds of agents in any of hundreds of databases.  It could also be a LEI (or whatever the product is called these days) task. If you have access to the server log, you might find a clue in there, especially if you know what time the file is created.

Comment: @Duston Thank you for your response. I have checked the LEI where job has been created that run on daily basis. but still facing the issue. I check the log in that only start time and end time are shown. But I am not aware hot to check the log details such as it's pick the text file from folder or not. even i am not sure that is the particular job will work for me. If you have any idea that we can set a new automated job to fetch the information from share folder ?

Comment: If you have a log entry, then you have most of what you need.  For example: 
"02/04/2021 05:25:51 AM  AMgr: Start executing agent '(Housecleaning) | aaHousecleaning' in 'reports.nsf' by Executive '7"' tells you the database name (reports.nsf) and the name of the agent ('(Housecleaning) | aaHousecleaning) .  You'd need the Designer client (and at least Designer access) to the databases and you and see exactly what it's doing.

Comment: @Duston I am working on prod database. I have only read access in LEI to see the job.I can do changes only in the database where information are stored.

Comment: Ask an Administrator of the system, they are supposed to know.

Comment: @D.Bugger Thank you for your response. I have checked with admin team, they mentioned like that there many jobs are executed in LEI for different purpose. As per my understand I have found one job and they executed manually but still file not moved from share folder to database.

Comment: LEI reading from text file: https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/10.0.1/basic/H_TEXT_CONNECTION_DOCUMENT_FOR_LEI_928_OVER.html , is that how it's configured? And just a suggestion: update your question (above) with relevant information and with the purpose of the question?

Answer (score 0):

The way I would start looking for this is by using the Design Synopsis feature to generate a listing of all agents in the NSF file for the application. You can search that listing for the name of the folder. If you find a hit, backtrack a bit in the listing to find the name of the agent.

The thing is, this job could be running as an agent in any database, not just the one where the data resides. (I have often designed systems with "Agent Container" databases.) The job could also be running on an ETL server somewhere else on the network, or it could be running as a script launched by the operating system's scheduler elsewhere on the network. Hopefully, it's not one of those things, but even if it is in an agent in the target NSF file, you still might not find the folder name. The agent could be reading the folder name from a profile document in the NSF file, or from a configuration document in some other NSF file.

But that's where I'd start.

Comment: Yup, it could be as simple as that, or it could be a needle in a haystack.

Comment: I'd propose a _Tell amgr sched_ in the Domino Admin client... It could even be some external application uploading data using the COM interface, or DIIOP, or JDBC.

Comment: @Richard,@D.Bugger Thank you for response. As per my understanding, we are using only LEI and lotus notes database. I have checked in database I found some agent job. When running this agent job getting error "The specified agent does not exist". Can you please tell me why I am getting this error and how we can resolve?

Comment: That should be the subject of a new question and you should include the code for the agent and also describe exactly how you are running the agent.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I have found the agent job in database which move the files forcefully.